# best feature to compare openCV contours

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

what are best features to detect a contour by comparison to a saved one? 
for now i have the following on the table and will use ratios between some of them (preliminary results are good):
-enclosing area circle
-bounding rectangle area
-bounding rectangle height over width
-perimeter (arc length)
-convex hull polygon area (using the polygon area formula)

which ones will be most distinct between different shapes and will be most accurate when compared (ratioA - ratioB < threshold) so i dont waste computing power on all together? 
ps: should also work with scale and rotation

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could edit your question by adding your CODE and explain them.

Comment: Like the best in the world or good in general?

Comment: [Image moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment)/Hu invariants can give good descriptors of shapes. See [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT2/node3.html) for derivation of these properties. You can further combine this with relationships between certain shapes (if there are relationships), like if you're tracking multiple objects in different frames you pick a distinct object matching between both frames and assign the rest of the objects labels based on their angle from the distinct object (which is thus rotation and scale invariant).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [module](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/shape/doc/shape_distances.html) `shape` in OpenCV that contains two shape comparators: `ShapeContextDistanceExtractor` and `HausdorffDistanceExtractor`. Both require only two contours as arguments and return single number (a distance between these contours in some space) that you can treat as a **measure of dissimilarity**.

Easier way is to try `cv::matchShapes()`: this function calculates two vectors of invariant [Hu moments](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Image_moment) for each contour and then calculates their dissimilarity based on these vectors as well.